# How to swap image in Android

Tags: android

I have four images and I want to swap image with each other. For example if I drag the second image into first image then first image placed in second image postion and second image placed in first image postion.

Comment: What does this have to do with the D programming language?

Comment: no sir, we need for java

Comment: Did you try to use a ViewPager ? https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: This is not my requirement sir, Actually I have four different image view and I just want to swap image with each other.